# SQL Query - format data from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a very large query that returns the data in the following format:

```
ID           ACTION                    DATE
----------------------------------------------------------
1            RUN                       2018-02-15
1            ACTION 1                  2018-02-10
1            ACTION 2                  2018-02-01
1            RUN                       2018-02-02
1            RUN                       2018-02-03
1            RUN                       2018-02-11
1            RUN                       2018-02-13
2            RUN                       2018-02-15
2            ACTION 1                  2018-02-10
2            ACTION 2                  2018-02-05
2            RUN                       2018-02-02
2            RUN                       2018-02-03
2            RUN                       2018-02-11
2            RUN                       2018-02-13
```

I have to use this query as a subquery and get the data like this:

```
ID           RUNS_AFTER_ACTION_1                RUNS_AFTER_ACTION_2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            3                                  5
2            3                                  3
```

Basically, the Action 1 and Action 2 define the limits I need to know how many runs where per ID after Action 1 and Action 2 has been executed.

Comment: It would be nice to order the data according to the `id` and `date`

Comment: What if there is more than one `action X` per id?

Comment: @RadimBača: Then use latest Action X date (MAX (DATE))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when action = 'RUN' and date > action1_date then 1 else 0 end) as RUNS_AFTER_ACTION_1,
       sum(case when action = 'RUN' and date > action2_date then 1 else 0 end) as RUNS_AFTER_ACTION_2
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'ACTION 1' then date end) over (partition by id) as action1_date,
             max(case when action = 'ACTION 2' then date end) over (partition by id) as action2_date
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: congratulation for the 5th rank :)

Comment: Much appreciated, wasted 2 days on this the secret was the partition by! Thank you!